# Flutter, dart not able to get required output from function

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a button which calls same function on every tap,
The function takes some time to complete (2-3) seconds and I want to stop the execution which was called on first tap if i tap that button again before completing (2-3) seconds of first tap
I mean if I tap the button twice I want output received from second tap.

What is happening:
Suppose first tap takes 5 seconds to complete and second tap 2 seconds, after 2 seconds of pressing  second tap the app will setState using second tap output (because it will finish earlier than first tap), but when 5 seconds are passed (of first app) then the app sets the state according to first tap output.

In the end I want output from second tap

Comment: Why don't you disable the button while the function is running?

Comment: @Andrej actually it is not a button, the function is called in onChanged property of textfield.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`CancelableOperation`](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/CancelableOperation-class.html), you can cancel the first task when the user clicks for the second time. Then only the second task will complete and that is the result that will be used.

Comment: actually I'm not calling the function from button, the function is called from onChanged property of textfield. I will try cancelableopration.